# Does $ab=1$ imply $ba=1$ in a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with unity $1$ and let $a,b\in R$ be not [zero divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor)s. Is there any counterexample for:
$$ab=1\quad\Rightarrow \quad ba=1$$

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assume $ab=1$ and $b$ is not a zero-divisor.
Then $bab=b\cdot ab=b\cdot 1=b$, hence $(ba-1)b=0$, which implies $ba-1=0$ as $b$ is not a divisor of zero. Thus $ba=1$.

Comment: Nice. So the lesson to take home is that non-zero-divisors can be canceled without needing an inverse.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I think your reasoning works for associative ring. What happens if the ring is not associative and not alternative?

Answer (score 4):

If you drop the condition "no zero-divisors", there are counterexamples:

There are rings with elements which are left-invertible, but not right-invertible. Standard example: Consider a vector space $V$ with the countable infinite basis $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots\}$ and let $R$ be the endomorphism ring of $V$. Now the endomorphism $b$ induced by $v_1\mapsto v_2$, $v_2\mapsto v_3$, $v_3\mapsto v_4$ etc. is left-invertible, but not right-invertible. However, it is a right zero divisor in $R$.

(Explanation: I missed the condition "no zero-divisors" in the first place.)

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Right. But I missed the condition "no zero-divisors". So my counterexample is not correct.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I wonder what the correct answer to your question is :) However, I guess that these not right-invertible counterexamples fail at not being zero-divisors.

Comment: by zero divisor I don't mean a two-sided one.

Comment: +1 Nice example!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ $ Exploit *conjugation* $\rm\ \ 1\!-\!ba\, =\, b\, (1\!-\!ab)\, b^{-1}.\ $ [Multiply it by $\rm\:b\:$ to eliminate $\rm\:b^{-1}]$

**Remark** $\ $ To learn more about such look up "Dedekind finite" rings. You might also enjoy this [tantalizing Halmos problem:](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31595/how-would-you-solve-this-tantalizing-halmos-problem) explain why the following formal power series "proof" of the fact that if $\rm\:(1\!-\!ab)^{-1}\:$ exists then $\rm\:(1\!-\!ba)^{-1}\:$ exists, and has the value

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray} (1\!−\!ba)^{−1} &=&\rm 1+ba+b\color{#C00}{ab}a+b\color{#0A0}{abab}a+\ \cdots \\
&=&\rm 1+b(1\!+\,\color{#C00}{ab}\ \ \,+\ \ \color{#0A0}{abab}\ \ +\ \cdots)\,a\\ &=&\rm 1+b(1\!−\!ab)^{-1} a\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: You write "hint", but you give the answer! :confus:

Comment: @Peter Now it's more of a hint, decorated with a Halmos gem.

Comment: =) I bumped into that nice solution a while ago.

Comment: Thanks Math Gems . I have an answer . We have $1+bca=(1-ab)^{-1}$ with $c=(1-ba)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

We can give an automated proof of this result using [Prover9](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/).  We input the ring axioms, and the assumption of $1$ and no zero divisors, and the goal $xy=1 \implies yx=1$ as follows:

```
formulas(assumptions).

  (x + y) + z = x + (y + z).  % + is associative
  x + y = y + x.  % + is commutative

  x + 0 = x.  % additive identity
  0 + x = x.

  x + -x = 0.  % additive inverse
  -x + x = 0.

  x * (y + z) = (x * y) + (x * z).  % distributivity
  (x + y) * z = (x * z) + (y * z).

  (x * y) * z = x * (y * z). % * is associative

  x * 1 = x.  % multiplicative identity
  1 * x = x.

  x * y = 0 -> (x = 0 | y = 0).  % no zero divisors

end_of_list.

formulas(goals).

  x * y = 1 -> y * x = 1.

end_of_list.
```

Here's the proof it generates:

```
============================== PROOF =================================

% Proof 1 at 0.03 (+ 0.01) seconds.
% Length of proof is 42.
% Level of proof is 11.
% Maximum clause weight is 17.
% Given clauses 87.

1 x * y = 0 -> x = 0 | y = 0 # label(non_clause).  [assumption].
2 x * y = 1 -> y * x = 1 # label(non_clause) # label(goal).  [goal].
3 (x + y) + z = x + (y + z).  [assumption].
4 x + y = y + x.  [assumption].
5 x + 0 = x.  [assumption].
6 0 + x = x.  [assumption].
7 x + -x = 0.  [assumption].
9 x * (y + z) = (x * y) + (x * z).  [assumption].
10 (x + y) * z = (x * z) + (y * z).  [assumption].
11 (x * y) * z = x * (y * z).  [assumption].
12 x * 1 = x.  [assumption].
13 1 * x = x.  [assumption].
14 x * y != 0 | 0 = x | 0 = y.  [clausify(1)].
15 c1 * c2 = 1.  [deny(2)].
16 1 = c1 * c2.  [copy(15),flip(a)].
17 c2 * c1 != 1.  [deny(2)].
18 c2 * c1 != c1 * c2.  [copy(17),rewrite([16(4)])].
20 c1 * (c2 * x) = x.  [back_rewrite(13),rewrite([16(1),11(4)])].
21 x * (c1 * c2) = x.  [back_rewrite(12),rewrite([16(1)])].
22 x + (y + z) = y + (x + z).  [para(4(a,1),3(a,1,1)),rewrite([3(2)])].
23 x + (-x + y) = y.  [para(7(a,1),3(a,1,1)),rewrite([6(2)]),flip(a)].
27 (x * 0) + (x * y) = x * y.  [para(6(a,1),9(a,1,2)),flip(a)].
28 (x * y) + (x * -y) = x * 0.  [para(7(a,1),9(a,1,2)),flip(a)].
29 (x * y) + (0 * y) = x * y.  [para(5(a,1),10(a,1,1)),flip(a)].
32 (x * y) + (x * z) != 0 | 0 = x | y + z = 0.  [para(9(a,1),14(a,1)),flip(c)].
40 x + (y + -x) = y.  [para(7(a,1),22(a,1,2)),rewrite([5(2)]),flip(a)].
42 --x = x.  [para(7(a,1),23(a,1,2)),rewrite([5(2)]),flip(a)].
62 -x + (y + x) = y.  [para(42(a,1),40(a,1,2,2))].
109 x * 0 = 0.  [para(27(a,1),62(a,1,2)),rewrite([4(4),7(4)]),flip(a)].
111 (x * y) + (x * -y) = 0.  [back_rewrite(28),rewrite([109(6)])].
112 x * (0 * y) = 0 * y.  [para(109(a,1),11(a,1,1)),flip(a)].
131 -(x * -y) = x * y.  [para(111(a,1),62(a,1,2)),rewrite([4(5),6(5)])].
135 x + (0 * (c2 * x)) = x.  [para(20(a,1),29(a,1,1)),rewrite([20(9)])].
139 x * -y = -(x * y).  [para(131(a,1),42(a,1,1)),flip(a)].
144 -(0 * (c2 * x)) = 0.  [para(135(a,1),23(a,1,2)),rewrite([7(2),139(5),139(6)]),flip(a)].
147 -(0 * x) = 0.  [para(112(a,1),144(a,1,1,2)),rewrite([112(4)])].
148 0 * x = 0.  [para(147(a,1),7(a,1,2)),rewrite([4(4),6(4)])].
156 (c1 * x) + y != 0 | c1 = 0 | x + (c2 * y) = 0.  [para(20(a,1),32(a,1,2)),flip(b)].
321 c1 = 0 | x + -(c2 * (c1 * x)) = 0.  [resolve(156,a,40,a),rewrite([6(9),139(8)])].
354 c1 = 0 | c2 * (c1 * x) = x.  [para(321(b,1),23(a,1,2)),rewrite([5(5),139(7),139(8),42(9)]),flip(b)].
368 c1 = 0.  [para(21(a,1),354(b,1,2)),unit_del(b,18)].
380 $F.  [back_rewrite(18),rewrite([368(2),109(3),368(2),148(4)]),xx(a)].

============================== end of proof ==========================
```

Yes, it's not easy for a human to read, but there's something final about having a computerised proof since it uses low-level logic (and there's also a "cool" factor).

Answer (score 0):

Let $(M, \cdot, e)$ be a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). We have a morphism from $M$ to the monoid of $\mathcal{F}(M)$ of functions from $M$ to $M$, by $a \mapsto L_a$, where $L_a(b) = a \cdot b$. Clearly it maps invertible elements to invertible elements in $\mathcal{F}(M)$, that is, to bijective functions. Conversely, if $a\in M$ is such that $L_a$ is bijective, then $a$ is invertible in $M$. Indeed, since $L_a$ is surjective, there exists  $b\in M$ such that $L_a(b) = e$, that is,
$a b = e$. To show that $a$ is invertible, we need to check that $b a= e$, or, since $L_a$ injective, $a( b a) = a e$. By associativity the LHS equals $(a b) a = e a = a = a e$, and we are done.

If $M$ is the multiplicative monoid of an associative ring $R$, then:

1. $L_a$ is surjective if and only if $a b = e$ for some $b$ ( $a$ has a [right inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element)). Indeed, $a b = e$ implies $a b c = c$.
2. $L_a$ is injective if and only if $a$ is not a [left zero divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor)