# Find $(1-ba)^{-1}$ when $c=(1-ab)^{-1} $ in ring $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For $R$ is a ring has identity element. $a,b\in R$ and  $c=(1-ab)^{-1}$ . Find $(1-ba)^{-1}$.

Comment: In my question : $R$ is a ring  not real field . I haven't ideal to find the inverse element of $(1-ba)^{-1}$ From supposition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ The answer is easily *discoverable* by examining geometric formal power series expansions, as below. It is simple algebra to prove that the derived formula is correct. 
$$\rm\begin{eqnarray} (1\!−\!ba)^{−1} &=&\rm 1+ba+b\color{#C00}{ab}a+b\color{#0A0}{abab}a+\ \cdots \\
&=&\rm 1+b(1\!+\,\color{#C00}{ab}\ \ \,+\ \ \color{#0A0}{abab}\ \ +\ \cdots)\,a\\ &=&\rm \ \ldots\end{eqnarray}$$

**Remark** $\ $ This is an old chestnut which Halmos made famous by asking for an explanation why the formal manipulations work. Some interesting explanations are known. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/353024/23500) for more.

Answer (score 2):

$x$ is the inverse of $1 - ab$. $(1 - ba)bxa = b(1-ab)xa = ba$. Therefore, $(1 - ba)(1 + bxa) = 1 - ba + ba = 1$. It is easy to verify that $(1 + bxa)(1 - ba) = 1$. Hence, $1 - ba$ is invertible.